# Twig Template - Div Element Being Inserted in Link URL

Tags: theming

I have a link field type that I'm referencing in a Twig template.  I'm using this code:

```
<div class="outlined">
<a href="{{content.field_3_column_image_link}}">{{content.field_3_column_image}}</a>
</div>
```

...BUT when I hover over the link I am seeing `https://nameofsite/<div>/node/1</div>` instead of `https://nameofsite/node/1`.

Can someone help me figure out why this is happening? Where are these divs coming from?

Thanks!
Bryan

Comment: Yes, thank you! {{content.field_3_column_image_link.0}} did the trick and stripped out the divs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comment from Patrick Kenny; the link he referred me to had the answer: I just had to use this insted: `{{content.field_3_column_image_link.0}}`.

Apparently the `.0` at the end of the filed type name strips out everything but the raw value.